# Intuition about amount of "circleness" as measured by power of $\pi$ in the formula

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I have been recently watching some videos on popular math where authors were talking about e.g. computing $\int_\Bbb R \mathrm e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx $ or series in the Basel problem, trying to answer how does $\pi$ appear there. They've applied logic *if you see a $\pi$ in the formula, there should be a circle somewhere*. Definitely, one can question this statement, but since $\pi$ is defined using a circle, it seems that this approach does have some merit. They did not try explaining Ramanujan's formulas, fortunately.

Nevertheless, this made me think of the following: in some of the expressions above $\pi$ appears with some power, due to how "circle" appearing in the solution connects to the answer of the problem. Say, $\int_\Bbb R \mathrm e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx$ is $\sqrt\pi$ since the circle appears when we square the integral, whereas in the Basel series there is $\pi^2$ due to dependence on the amount of light some area receives from a lighthouse depending on the distance between them.

Yet, in school math we deal with a lot of geometric objects whose measures only have the first power of $\pi$ in their expression: length of a (1d) circle, area of a (2d) disk, area of a (2d) sphere and volume of a (3d) ball. Intuitively it seems, that all of them are somehow "round" up to degree $1$, even though those are objects from 3 distinct dimensions.

At the same time, a $0$d or 1d ball does not have any roundness as we can "see" when we draw it, and this is also reflected in the absence of $\pi$ in the formulas of their natural measures (Lebesgue/Hausdorff). Similarly, once we go the dimensions above $3$ the balls and spheres will have higher degrees of $\pi$ in their dependence on their radius.

My question is: what is the intuition that under all these circumstance a circle, a disk, a sphere and a ball has the first power of $\pi$ in dependence between their measure and their radius, even though they span different dimensions?

Comment: The main identity you want is $V_n(R)=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R V_{n-2}(\sqrt{R^2-r^2}) r dr d\theta$ for $n>2$. The idea there is that you get a "new circle" every time you peel off *two* dimensions, since you need two coordinates to be in a disk while the other coordinates lie in a $(n-2)$-ball. Then each circle you peel off generates a new multiple of $\pi$ until you can no longer peel circles off. Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball